# Extra large modal for bootstrap with 90% of the window size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a need to have a modal that stretches to almost the 100% of the current window save for the usual gutters to the left and right.

I have this code

```
<div class="modal fade " id="mapstays" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl verybigmodal" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Show On Map</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
```

and this css

```
.verybigmodal{
  width:1000px !important;
}
```

which doesn't stretch the modal or give it the desired width. Is there a way i can stretch the modal beyond the limits of `modal-xl`?

Comment: Check the `max-width` for the modal

Comment: That works `.verybigmodal{
  max-width:97% !important;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `max-width` to overide Bootstrap's max-width:

```
.verybigmodal {
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/uzzf7dMsJe)

Comment: it's better use ```min-width```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `min-width` combined with `display: block`. By default `div` has `display: block`, but may be it got overriden:

```
.verybigmodal {
  display: block;
  min-width:1000px !important;
}
```

or try to use [vh](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/):

```
.verybigmodal {
  display: block;
  min-width:100vh !important;
}
```